# Android audio over HSF bluetooth connection using a virtual call

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to send audio over my cars speakers without having the cars audio input set to bluetooth. It supports the A2DP profile, and I also managed to get it to work. But that only works when I manually set the input to Bluetooth.

But I would like to 'force' the audio being sent over the speakers.

I previously had an iPhone. The Google Maps app would 'call' itself everything it would pronounce the directions. So my car would see it is an incoming call and play the audio over the speakers.

I looked around the internet, and it seems I need to use the HSF profile to pull of the same trick.

The documentation states that HSF is supported, but it does not show me how to do it. I also found exactly what I needed in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setBluetoothScoOn(boolean)). It states the following:

> NOTE: up to and including API version JELLY_BEAN_MR1, this method initiates a virtual voice call to the bluetooth headset. After API version JELLY_BEAN_MR2 only a raw SCO audio connection is established.

So initiating virtual voice calls **was** possible. I would like to know how to do that now. Any other ideas on how to do this would also be very helpfull.